# Empty Magento URL if(empty()

Tags: magento-1.9

```
$image_url = $main_product->getImageUrl();
```

If this is empty I'm receiving an error.

```
Image file was not found.

    Trace:
    #0 /home/***/***/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('no_selection')
```

I'm just trying to put a place holder in

```
if(empty($image_url){ "http://PlaceholderURL.com" }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code, it will automatically check and replace missing images with default placeholder:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($main_product, 'image')
```

You can also resize or modify the image if you need (e.g.:):

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($main_product, 'image')->resize(400)->keepFrame(true);
```

Comment: Didn't work for use, but what we where actually missing was the 'placeholder' from the store. Had to assign each one. Easy oversite and thanks for input.